# Wait for callback in createWriteStreamToBlockBlob

Tags: node.js, azure, stream, azure-storage

I'm trying to pipe a stream to Azure's createWriteStreamToBlockBlob but I can't get it to wait until the callback returns before piping to the next part. I need the callback to return before the stream gets to firstLine. Both the blobStream stream and firstLine stream end before the callback.

```
var blobStream = blobService.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob(config.STORAGE_CONTAINER, _blobFilePath,
        function(err, result){
            console.log(result);
    })
    .on("end", function() {
        console.log("finished");
    })

busboy
    .on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        file
        .pipe(blobStream)
        .pipe(firstLine)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback function will only be triggered after “finish” event of `writeStream` emitted. Although we can pipe a readStream into mulit writeStreams, we can’t split pipe into steps.

If you have to handle with the result of Azure function before pipe into `firstLine` stream, you can store the file in a temp file, then pipe into `firstLine` in callback closure.

```
var blobStream = blobsrv.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob(container, filename,
        function (err, result, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log(result);
            console.log(res);
            fs.createReadStream('tmpfile.txt').pipe(firstLine);
        }
    })
busboy
    .on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        var r = file
        .pipe(blobStream)
        .pipe(new fs.createWriteStream('tmpfile.txt'));
   })
```

If you just need handle the first line of the content, you can handle it in “data” event of createWriteStreamToBlockBlob().

```
var blobStream = blobsrv.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob(container, filename,
        function (err, result, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
           console.log(result);
           console.log(res);
       }
    })
    .on("data", function (chunk){
        console.log("get data : "+chunk);
    })
```